# Lost in validation design

Tags: c#, jquery

I need some ideas... I have a SQL table that contains error codes, and messages that I will use to display in the web application based on the code column for validation purposes.

If by using server side to do checking, I can load the messages whenever they hit the condition by matching with the error code I put, and display at the menu. But each time a post back needs to be done to show the error code and message, by using the update panel, I can do a partial postback, still I can't style as I want.

If I using client script to check. i can style as I want, but I will need to load the error code and message on each pageload, and chop it 1 by 1, javascript to process and based on code, show the error message, I dont think it is a good idea, is there any better idea to achieve this? I kinda stuck due to my limited knowledge, any idea will be great, thanks

Comment: As it currently stands this question is not in a good format for the site

Comment: Why do you say you can't style it as you want?  Why can't you?  What makes it impossible

Comment: Like color the border With red color? Server side code can do that?